# A managed resource has not been declared in module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-gcp

I've a two modules under modules directory named as prienv and vpc

```
nnice@MPL-G8WW7D3:~/terra-test/modules/prienv$ pwd
/home/nnice/terra-test/modules/prienv
nnice@MPL-G8WW7D3:~/terra-test/modules/prienv$ ls
data.tf  main.tf  variable.tf
```

**Here is my data.tf file under prienv module**

```
nnice@MPL-G8WW7D3:~/terra-test/modules/prienv$ cat data.tf
data "aws_security_groups" "mysg-data" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["MySG"]
  }
  depends_on = [aws_security_groups.mysg]
}

data "aws_subnet" "myprisn-data" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["MyPriSN"]
  }
  depends_on = [aws_subnet.myprisn]
}
```

**Here is my variable.tf file under prienv module**

```
variable "pri_av" {
  description = "for private availability zone"
  type        = string
  default     = "us-east-1b"
}

variable "ami" {
  description = "ami for ec2"
  type        = string
  default     = "ami-03ededff12e34e59e"
}

variable "instance_type" {
  description = "Instance type t2.micro"
  type        = string
  default     = "t2.micro" #will use double quotes for string type
}

variable "key_pair" {
  description = "key pair for ec2"
  type        = string
  default     = "learner_key"
}

variable "instance_count" {
  description = "EC2 instance count"
  type        = number
  default     = 1 #here we're using it to create two private instances
}

variable "project_environment" {
  description = "project name and environment for private instances"
  type        = map(string)
  default = {
    project     = "private", # it works upon key value pair where project is for key and environment is value
    environment = "testing"  # you will find them under tag on aws console
  }
}
```

**And this is my main.tf file under prienv module**

```
resource "aws_instance" "mypriec2" {
  ami               = var.ami
  instance_type     = var.instance_type
  count             = var.instance_count
  availability_zone = var.pri_av
  #subnet_id              = aws_subnet.myprisn.id
  subnet_id = data.aws_subnet.myprisn-data.id
  #vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.mysg.id]
  vpc_security_group_ids = data.aws_security_groups.mysg-data.ids
  key_name               = var.key_pair
  # disable_api_termination = true
  tags = var.project_environment
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "mykeypair" {
  key_name   = var.key_pair
  public_key = "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NaffrWscf59juCakElys9F3+zVuz0ta4gRUtKgWVPIj6ACr00VNDzsTTW2/sSjYtE5zWolVKCITlhqiIhgRKUDLKoxclxUKnK6IGIafdaefafaheiufa;fdaeoasfdkQvNtGrrHzY5/dbZhIUTxDUyvT5O5U= nnice@MPL-G8WW7D3"
}
```

**and here is my vpc moduls**

```
nnice@MPL-G8WW7D3:~/terra-test/modules/vpc$ pwd
/home/nnice/terra-test/modules/vpc
nnice@MPL-G8WW7D3:~/terra-test/modules/vpc$ ls
data.tf  main.tf  variable.tf
```

**This is my data.tf file under vpc module**

```
nnice@MPL-G8WW7D3:~/terra-test/modules/vpc$ cat data.tf
data "aws_vpc" "myvpc-data" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["MyVPC"]
  }
  depends_on = [aws_vpc.myvpc]
}

data "aws_subnet" "mypubsn-data" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["MyPubSN"]
  }
  depends_on = [aws_subnet.mypubsn]
}

data "aws_subnet" "myprisn-data" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["MyPriSN"]
  }
  depends_on = [aws_subnet.myprisn]
}
```

**This is my main.tf file under vpc module**

```
nnice@MPL-G8WW7D3:~/terra-test/modules/vpc$ cat main.tf
##################################################################
############################## VPC ###############################
##################################################################

resource "aws_vpc" "myvpc" {
  cidr_block       = var.vpc_cidr
  instance_tenancy = var.vpc_tenancy

  tags = {
    Name = var.vpc_tag
  }
}

##################################################################
############################# Subnet #############################
##################################################################

#PUBLIC SUBNET
resource "aws_subnet" "mypubsn" {
  #vpc_id                 = aws_vpc.myvpc.id
  vpc_id                  = data.aws_vpc.myvpc-data.id
  cidr_block              = var.mypubsn_cidr
  availability_zone       = var.pub_av
  map_public_ip_on_launch = var.map_public_ip_on_launch
  tags = {
    Name = var.mypubsn_tag
  }
}

#PRIVATE SUBNET
resource "aws_subnet" "myprisn" {
  #vpc_id            = aws_vpc.myvpc.id
  vpc_id            = data.aws_vpc.myvpc-data.id
  cidr_block        = var.myprisn_cidr
  availability_zone = var.pri_av

  tags = {
    Name = var.myprisn_tag
  }
}

##################################################################
############################### IGW ##############################
##################################################################

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "myigw" {
  #vpc_id = aws_vpc.myvpc.id
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.myvpc-data.id
  tags = {
    Name = var.igw_tag
  }
}

##################################################################
############################ Route Table #########################
##################################################################

#PUBLIC RT
resource "aws_route_table" "mypubrt" {
  #vpc_id = aws_vpc.myvpc.id
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.myvpc-data.id

  tags = {
    Name = var.mypubsn_tag
  }
}

#PRIVATE RT
resource "aws_route_table" "myprirt" {
  #vpc_id = aws_vpc.myvpc.id
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.myvpc-data.id

  tags = {
    Name = var.myprisn_tag
  }
}

####################################################################
######################## Route Table Associate #####################
####################################################################

#PUBLIC RT association
resource "aws_route_table_association" "pub" {
  #subnet_id      = aws_subnet.mypubsn.id
  subnet_id      = data.aws_subnet.mypubsn-data.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.mypubrt.id
}

#PRIVATE RT association
resource "aws_route_table_association" "pri" {
  #subnet_id      = aws_subnet.myprisn.id
  subnet_id      = data.aws_subnet.myprisn-data.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.myprirt.id
}

###################################################################
########################### Route #################################
###################################################################

#PUBLIC Route
resource "aws_route" "mypubroute" {
  route_table_id         = aws_route_table.mypubrt.id
  destination_cidr_block = var.pubroute
  gateway_id             = aws_internet_gateway.myigw.id
  depends_on             = [aws_route_table.mypubrt]
}

#PRIVATE Route
#resource "aws_route" "mypriroute" {
#  route_table_id            = aws_route_table.myprirt.id
#  destination_cidr_block    = "0.0.0.0/0"
#  gateway_id             = aws_internet_gateway.myigw.id
#  depends_on                = [aws_route_table.myprirt]
#}

###################################################################
############################ SG ###################################
###################################################################

resource "aws_security_group" "mysg" {
  name        = "MySecurityGroup"
  description = "Allow TLS inbound traffic"
  #vpc_id      = aws_vpc.myvpc.id
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.myvpc-data.id

  ingress {
    description = "TLS from VPC"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    # cidr_blocks      = [aws_vpc.myvpc.cidr_block]
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    # ipv6_cidr_blocks = [aws_vpc.main.ipv6_cidr_block]
  }

  ingress {
    description = "TLS from VPC"
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    # cidr_blocks      = [aws_vpc.myvpc.cidr_block]
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    # ipv6_cidr_blocks = [aws_vpc.main.ipv6_cidr_block]
  }

  egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = var.SG_tag
  }
}
```

**And this is my variable.tf file under vpc module**

```
nnice@MPL-G8WW7D3:~/terra-test/modules/vpc$ cat variable.tf
variable "vpc_tenancy" {
  description = "vpc instance tenancy"
  type        = string
  default     = "default"
}

variable "pub_av" {
  description = "for public availability zone"
  type        = string
  default     = "us-east-1a"
}

variable "pri_av" {
  description = "for private availability zone"
  type        = string
  default     = "us-east-1b"
}

variable "vpc_tag" {
  description = "Tag for VPC"
  type        = string
  default     = "MyVPC"
}

variable "vpc_cidr" {
  description = "for vpc cidr"
  type        = string
  default     = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

variable "mypubsn_cidr" {
  description = "for public subnet cidr"
  type        = string
  default     = "10.0.1.0/24"
}

variable "myprisn_cidr" {
  description = "for private subnet cidr"
  type        = string
  default     = "10.0.2.0/24"
}

variable "mypubsn_tag" {
  description = "tag for public subnet"
  type        = string
  default     = "MyPubSN"
}

variable "myprisn_tag" {
  description = "tag for private subnet"
  type        = string
  default     = "MyPriSN"
}

variable "igw_tag" {
  description = "tag for IGW subnet"
  type        = string
  default     = "MyIGW"
}

variable "pubrt_tag" {
  description = "tag for private subnet"
  type        = string
  default     = "MyPubRT"
}

variable "prirt_tag" {
  description = "tag for IGW subnet"
  type        = string
  default     = "MyPriRT"
}

variable "pubroute" {
  description = "cidr for public route"
  type        = string
  default     = "0.0.0.0/0"
}

variable "SG_tag" {
  description = "tag for SG"
  type        = string
  default     = "MySG"
}

variable "map_public_ip_on_launch" {
  description = "auto enable public ip to public subnet"
  type        = bool
  default     = true
}
```

And there is env directory where I have my main.tf file

```
nnice@MPL-G8WW7D3:~/terra-test$ ls
env  modules
nnice@MPL-G8WW7D3:~/terra-test$ cd env/private-ec2/
nnice@MPL-G8WW7D3:~/terra-test/env/private-ec2$ pwd
/home/nnice/terra-test/env/private-ec2
nnice@MPL-G8WW7D3:~/terra-test/env/private-ec2$ ls
main.tf
nnice@MPL-G8WW7D3:~/terra-test/env/private-ec2$ cat main.tf
#Provider

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

#VPC
 
module "vpc" {
  source = "../../modules/vpc"
}

#EC2

module "prienv" {
  source = "../../modules/prienv"
}
```

When I'm trying to run terraform plan, I'm getting following errors

```
 Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on ../../modules/prienv/data.tf line 6, in data "aws_security_groups" "mysg-data":
│    6:   depends_on = [aws_security_groups.mysg]
│
│ A managed resource "aws_security_groups" "mysg" has not been declared in module.prienv.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on ../../modules/prienv/data.tf line 14, in data "aws_subnet" "myprisn-data":
│   14:   depends_on = [aws_subnet.myprisn]
│
│ A managed resource "aws_subnet" "myprisn" has not been declared in module.prienv.
```

Could anyone please let me know its solution? I already using vpc module in my main.tf file

Comment: In addition to the answer provided below, just some recommendations how to improve your question: 
1.  Try to create a minimal reproducible example - your example is quite huge and a large number of the lines is not required to understand the issue and it makes it difficult to find the important ones.
2. in particular remove any code that you commented out in your source.
3. Use `terraform fmt` to bring your code to a common standard format before posting
There are quite some folks around her who will vote your question down if such standards are not met.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are running into is that `aws_security_groups.mysg`and `aws_subnet.myprisn` are locally defined in the vpc module but you are referencing them in the `depends_on` statement in the prienv module.

Also the [Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/depends_on) suggests that the `depends_on` argument

> should be used only as a last resort.

So the way to go would be, to define the security group and the subnet as an output in the vpc module, as variable in the prienv module, and then passing the outputs of vpc as parameter values to prienv.
This way terraform will recognize the dependencies between the resources from the dependency graph it creates and you won't neet the `depends_on` argument.

So in consequence, the diffs to your config could look like:

**`modules/vpc/outputs.tf`**

```
output "sec_group" {
  value       = aws_security_group.mysg
  description = "..."
}

output "subnet" {
  value       = aws_subnet.myprisn
  description = "..."
}
```

**`modules/prienv/variable.tf`**

```
variable "sec_group" {
  description = "..."
}

variable "subnet" {
  description = "..."
}
```

**`modules/prienv/main.tf`**

```
resource "aws_instance" "mypriec2" {
  ...
  subnet_id              = var.subnet.id
  vpc_security_group_ids = var.sec_group.ids
  ...
}
```

**`env/main.tf`**

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "../../modules/vpc"
}

#EC2

module "prienv" {
  source    = "../../modules/prienv"
  sec_group = module.vpc.sec_group
  subnet    = module.vpc.subnet
}
```